# How to get friendly device name from DEV_BROADCAST_DEVICEINTERFACE and Device Instance ID

Tags: c#, winapi, guid, device-instance-id

I've registered a window with [RegisterDeviceNotification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363431%28VS.85%29.aspx) and can successfully recieve [DEV_BROADCAST_DEVICEINTERFACE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363244%28VS.85%29.aspx) messages. However, the `dbcc_name` field in the returned struct is always empty. The struct I have is defined as such:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct DEV_BROADCAST_DEVICEINTERFACE
{
    public int dbcc_size;
    public int dbcc_devicetype;
    public int dbcc_reserved;
    public Guid dbcc_classguid;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]
    public string dbcc_name;
}
```

And I'm using `Marshal.PtrToStructure` on the LParam of the [WM_DEVICECHANGE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363480%28VS.85%29.aspx) message.

Should this be working?

Or even better... Is there an alternative way to get the name of a device upon connection?

**EDIT (02/05/2010 20:56GMT):**

I found out how to get the dbcc_name field to populate by doing this:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
public struct DEV_BROADCAST_DEVICEINTERFACE
{
    public int dbcc_size;
    public int dbcc_devicetype;
    public int dbcc_reserved;
    public Guid dbcc_classguid;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst=255)]
    public string dbcc_name;
}
```

but I still need a way to get a "Friendly" name from what is int dbcc_name. It looks like the following:

> \?\USB#VID_05AC&PID_1294&MI_00#0#{6bdd1fc6-810f-11d0-bec7-08002be2092f}

And I really just want it to say "Apple iPhone" (which is what the device is in this case).

Comment: I hope I'm wrong about this, but in the process of learning how to marshal these calls, I came to the conclusion that you _can't_ marshal `DEV_BROADCAST_DEVICEINTERFACE`, because it's a variable size struct (ends with an ANYSIZE array). The framework will get a pointer to a chunk of memory whose size is determined by the first struct member. Unless there's a way to tell the marshaler about that, I think you have to do this in native code (that's what I did).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Well, as noted above I found out how to get dbcc_name to populate correctly. I found that this was the easiest way to get the device name:

```
private static string GetDeviceName(DEV_BROADCAST_DEVICEINTERFACE dvi)
{
    string[] Parts = dvi.dbcc_name.Split('#');
    if (Parts.Length >= 3)
    {
        string DevType = Parts[0].Substring(Parts[0].IndexOf(@"?\") + 2);
        string DeviceInstanceId = Parts[1];
        string DeviceUniqueID = Parts[2];
        string RegPath = @"SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Enum\" + DevType + "\\" + DeviceInstanceId + "\\" + DeviceUniqueID;
        RegistryKey key = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(RegPath);
        if (key != null)
        {
            object result = key.GetValue("FriendlyName");
            if (result != null)
                return result.ToString();
            result = key.GetValue("DeviceDesc");
            if (result != null)
                return result.ToString();
        }
    }
    return String.Empty;
}
```

Comment: THANKS!! I've been trying to do the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

This information can also be acquired more formally through [SetupAPI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff550897%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Pass `dbcc_name` to `SetupDiOpenDeviceInterface` and get the friendly name with `SetupDiGetDeviceRegistryProperty` passing in `SPDRP_FRIENDLYNAME`.

Here's some Delphi code that will do it. (Sorry, you'll have to translate to C# independently).

```
function ConvertDbccNameToFriendlyName(aDeviceInterfaceDbccName : string) : string;
var
  deviceInfoHandle : HDEVINFO;
  deviceInfoData : SP_DEVINFO_DATA;
  deviceInterfaceData : SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DATA;
  deviceInstanceId : string;
  memberIndex : Cardinal;
begin
  result := '';

  // Create a new empty "device info set"
  deviceInfoHandle := SetupDiCreateDeviceInfoList(nil, 0);
  if deviceInfoHandle <> INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE then
  begin
    try
      // Add "aDeviceInterfaceDbccName" to the device info set
      FillChar(deviceInterfaceData, SizeOf(deviceInterfaceData), 0);
      deviceInterfaceData.cbSize := SizeOf(deviceInterfaceData);
      if SetupDiOpenDeviceInterface(deviceInfoHandle, PChar(aDeviceInterfaceDbccName),     0, @deviceInterfaceData) then
      begin
        try
          // iterate over the device info set
          // (though I only expect it to contain one item)
          memberIndex := 0;
          while true do
          begin
            // get device info that corresponds to the next memberIndex
            FillChar(deviceInfoData, SizeOf(deviceInfoData), 0);
            deviceInfoData.cbSize := SizeOf(deviceInfoData);
            if not SetupDiEnumDeviceInfo(deviceInfoHandle, memberIndex, deviceInfoData) then
            begin
              // The enumerator is exhausted when SetupDiEnumDeviceInfo returns false
              break;
            end
            else
            begin
              Inc(memberIndex);
            end;

            // Get the friendly name for that device info
            if TryGetDeviceFriendlyName(deviceInfoHandle, deviceInfoData, {out} friendlyName) then
            begin
              result := friendlyName;
              break;
            end;
          end;
        finally
          SetupDiDeleteDeviceInterfaceData(deviceInfoHandle, deviceInterfaceData);
        end;
      end;
    finally
      SetupDiDestroyDeviceInfoList(deviceInfoHandle);
    end;
  end;
end;

function TryGetDeviceFriendlyName(
  var aDeviceInfoHandle : HDEVINFO;
  var aDeviceInfoData : SP_DEVINFO_DATA;
  out aFriendlyName : string) : boolean;
var
  valueBuffer : array of byte;
  regProperty : Cardinal;
  propertyRegDataType : DWord;
  friendlyNameByteSize : Cardinal;
  success : boolean;
begin
  aFriendlyName := '';
  result := false;

  // Get the size of the friendly device name
  regProperty := SPDRP_FRIENDLYNAME;
  friendlyNameByteSize := 0;
  SetupDiGetDeviceRegistryProperty(
    aDeviceInfoHandle,     // handle to device information set
    aDeviceInfoData,       // pointer to SP_DEVINFO_DATA structure
    regProperty,           // property to be retrieved
    propertyRegDataType,   // pointer to variable that receives the data type of the property
    nil,                   // pointer to PropertyBuffer that receives the property
    0,                     // size, in bytes, of the PropertyBuffer buffer.
    friendlyNameByteSize); // pointer to variable that receives the required size of PropertyBuffer

  // Prepare a buffer for the friendly device name (plus space for a null terminator)
  SetLength(valueBuffer, friendlyNameByteSize + sizeof(char));

  success := SetupDiGetDeviceRegistryProperty(
    aDeviceInfoHandle,
    aDeviceInfoData,
    regProperty,
    propertyRegDataType,
    @valueBuffer[0],
    friendlyNameByteSize,
    friendlyNameByteSize);

  if success then
  begin
    // Ensure that only 'friendlyNameByteSize' bytes are used.
    // Ensure that the string is null-terminated.
    PChar(@valueBuffer[friendlyNameByteSize])^ := char(0);

    // Get the returned value as a string
    aFriendlyName := StrPas(PChar(@valueBuffer[0]));
  end;

  result := success;
end;
```

Finally... if you need a way to uniquely identify a USB device (not what you asked for, but commonly this is also needed), look into `SetupDiGetDeviceInstanceId`.

Comment: A bit late for answering. An answer has already been accepted with seven votes.

Comment: It's never too late for a better answer =)  (I prefer a formal API over manual string parsing any day)

Comment: @NathanSchubkegel if you can find someone to translate this to C#, I'll change the accepted answer. This would be the absolutely preferable solution, the code I posted above is smelly and relies on something always being in the same location in the registry (or the registry existing at all), a winapi solution is best

Comment: So is this in C#?

Answer (score 0):

It is likely you need to change this slightly

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct DEV_BROADCAST_DEVICEINTERFACE
{
    public int dbcc_size;
    public int dbcc_devicetype;
    public int dbcc_reserved;
    public Guid dbcc_classguid;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]
    public StringBuilder dbcc_name;
}
```

Set the `dbcc_size` to 255, and construct the StringBuilder as shown below:

```
DEV_BROADCAST_DEVICEINTERFACE dbd = new DEV_BROADCAST_DEVICEINTERFACE;
dbd.dbcc_size = 255;
dbd.dbcc_name = new StringBuilder(dbd.dbcc_size);
```

Then pass that structure in, the value of `dbcc_name` should be populated.

**Edit:** after ***snicker***'s comment...I thought of this another way...

```
public struct DEV_BROADCAST_DEVICEINTERFACE
{
    public int dbcc_size;
    public int dbcc_devicetype;
    public int dbcc_reserved;
    public Guid dbcc_classguid;
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.MarshalAsAttribute(System.Runtime.InteropServices.UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 255, ArraySubType = System.Runtime.InteropServices.UnmanagedType.LPArray)]
    public string dbcc_name;
}
```

Set the `dbcc_size` to 255, and take it from there...

**Edit#2:** This is interesting...am not so sure now, I found this article that uses `RegisterDeviceNotification` on [Codeproject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/DriveDetector.aspx) and it uses a different way of RegisterDeviceNotification in that the struct is marshalled into a `IntPtr` and is used to call the API...

Comment: You cannot marshal fields that are StringBuilders. This doesn't work.

Comment: Tom. Your edit still doesn't work. You can only marshal strings to LPStr, LPWStr, LPTStr, BStr, or ByValTStr.

Comment: @Snicker: have you tried changing the attribute '            [System.Runtime.InteropServices.MarshalAsAttribute(System.Runtime.InteropServices.UnmanagedType.LPStr, SizeConst = 255, ArraySubType = System.Runtime.InteropServices.UnmanagedType.LPStr)]'

Comment: The problem is not with RegisterDeviceNotification. The problem is marshaling a message into a new struct. It's possible the names just aren't coming though, but that seems unlikely