# How do I decode a PDEV_BROADCAST_DEVICEINTERFACE::dbcc_name?

Tags: .net, windows, c++-cli, type-conversion

I've been trying to watch a USB subsystem to detect when devices are added or removed, but I'm having trouble decoding the `PDEV_BROADCAST_DEVICEINTERFACE::dbcc_name` field. My code is based on [an example over on codeproject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/HwDetect.aspx).

If I right-click in my C++/CLI application in visual studio and go to the declaration in `Dbt.h` I get:

```
typedef struct _DEV_BROADCAST_DEVICEINTERFACE_W {
    DWORD       dbcc_size;
    DWORD       dbcc_devicetype;
    DWORD       dbcc_reserved;
    GUID        dbcc_classguid;
    wchar_t     dbcc_name[1];
} DEV_BROADCAST_DEVICEINTERFACE_W, *PDEV_BROADCAST_DEVICEINTERFACE_W;
```

Which suggests that the name should be a `wchar_t`. Feeding this into a new System::String just comes up with random characters. Is there more to converting a wchar_t string?

**[edit]** Essentially I want to do [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2208722/how-to-get-friendly-device-name-from-dev-broadcast-deviceinterface-and-device-ins) in C++-cli but how do I port that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No idea what "feeding" might mean.  Use Marshal::PtrToStringUni() to convert the string.  If the window that receives this message was created with CreateWindowExA() then you need Marshal::PtrToStringAnsi().

Comment: Feeding = passing and your suggestion (PtrToStringUni) seems to work well. Thanks very much - I was beginning to tear my heair out a little there! :-)