# Why is char not a single character?

Tags: c++, c, windows

In Microsoft's documentation for [DEV_BROADCAST_DEVICEINTERFACE_A](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/dbt/ns-dbt-dev_broadcast_deviceinterface_a) the type of `dbcc_name` is defined as follows:

```
char  dbcc_name[1];
```

But as shown in [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2208722/939213) it turns out to be a `string` with *multiple* characters.

Isn't a `char` a <s>16 bit value</s> single character? How does this work?

<sub>(I had originally thought that `char` is 16 bits. Presumably because that's its size in c#. Actually it was probably because I was looking at [DEV_BROADCAST_DEVICEINTERFACE_W](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/dbt/ns-dbt-dev_broadcast_deviceinterface_w) where it is indeed 2 bytes.)</sub>

Comment: `sizeof(char)` is always `1`, what that is in bits depends on `CHAR_BIT` (typically 8)

Comment: You must be confused with what a `char` is in some other computer languages.  A `char` in C++ has a size of 1, as stated in the previous comment.

Comment: `char dbcc_name[1];` is a stretchy buffer.  The structure is over-allocated as `malloc(sizeof(DEV_BROADCAST_DEVICEINTERFACE_A) + buffer_size)`, and the dbcc_name acts as the start of the variable length buffer.  It's sort of sketchy C code (but not uncommon), and very bad C++ code.  Note what [dbcc_size](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/dbt/ns-dbt-dev_broadcast_deviceinterface_a) is!

Comment: Sort of a [flexible array member](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flexible_array_member), except non-standard (and that's not in C++ anyway I believe). And chars are more often 8bits, not 16.

Comment: [This is the C# char](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/char).  Is this what causes the confusion?

Comment: @Eljay I called it C++ because that's what Microsoft calls it in the link in the question (As a c# dev, I don't know myself). Are you saying that Microsoft is using bad C++ code or that their documentation is bad?

Comment: @Mat I called it C++ because that's what Microsoft calls it in the link in the question. As a C# dev, I don't know myself.

Comment: @ispiro The problem is that all of the Windows API is `C`-based.  Anything C++ is something added by MFC or some other third-party wrapper around the Windows API.  That documentation is really meant for `C` programmers, and C++ programmers have to figure out if it can be used (probably over 99% of the API can be used straight out of the box), or workaround anything that may cause an issue with C++.

Comment: The situation with C++ and flexible array member (what we'd call a stretchy buffer, back in the day) has been discussed in depth in the comments in this SO question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4412749/are-flexible-array-members-valid-in-c

Comment: I think your question has a very good background, but the title should be adjusted. In general, `char` is always a datatype in C. It specify neither an aggregate nor a scalar variable.

Comment: Check out this question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/295027/14065

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Isn't a `char` a 16 bit value?

On what platform? On most platforms (including all that run Windows, AFAIK), `char` is 8 bits.

> How does this work?

The type documentation explains this:

> #### `dbcc_size`
>
> The size of this structure, in bytes. This is the size of the members plus the actual length of the dbcc_name string (the null character is accounted for by the declaration of dbcc_name as a one-character array.)

In other words, the definition of `_DEV_BROADCAST_DEVICEINTERFACE_A` exploits the fact that arrays decay to pointers in C++, and thus `dbcc_name`, which has array type, can be used as a zero-terminated string in most contexts. The actual string is stored contiguously with the `_DEV_BROADCAST_DEVICEINTERFACE_A` object, at the address starting at the offset of `dbcc_name`.

It’s worth noting that the size of the array (1) is unrelated to the length of its contents; it is simply the smallest legal static array size in C++ (legacy code occasionally uses struct members of type `char[0]`. However, this is a compiler extension and not legal C++).

Comment: The explanation is parens is saying that the null terminator is not included in the part of the `dbcc_size` value that excludes `sizeof(_DEV_BROADCAST_DEVICEINTERFACE_A)`, because the null terminator's slot has been accounted for in the array dimension included in the result of `sizeof`. Yes it's true that they _had_ to make give it a non-zero dimension, but I don't think that makes the statement misleading. I would probably argue, though, that it's an irrelevant implementation detail that distracts from the useful information.

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings Fair enough

Comment: Thanks. I'm not sure where I remembered the 16 bits from. Anyway, as a C# dev, I assumed that the `char` at the beginning of that line meant that the type _is_ char. According to your answer - `dbcc_name, which has array type` it seems that the brackets mean that it's really an array of chars. Did I understand you correctly?

Comment: @ispiro Declaration  syntax in C# is different from C and C++. In C and C++, you declare a static array as shown here, i.e. `Type name[Size]`. In hindsight that’s idiotic, which is why C# changed it to be sane (`Type[] name`). The original idea behind C’s declaration syntax was that declarations mirror usage: the type of `name[0]` is `Type` (i.e. the type of `dbcc_name[0]` is `char`).

Answer (score 3):

This is what is known as the "struct hack".  It's a trick that allows you to store variably-sized data in a `struct` instance.

You make the last member an array of size 1, like so:

```
struct foo { int i; char c[1] };
```

Assuming a 4-byte `int`, this type is 5 bytes wide (although it will likely take up 8 bytes to satisfy any alignment requirements), and an instance of `struct foo` would look like this:

```
   +---+
i: |   |
   +---+
   |   | 
   +---+
   |   |
   +---+
   |   | 
   +---+
c: |   |
   +---+
```

However, if you allocate memory for it dynamically with `malloc` or `calloc`, you can allocate more memory than just what's needed for the `struct` type and that extra memory will be considered part of the array (since `struct` elements are guaranteed to be laid out in the order declared and array types don't enforce sizes).

```
struct foo *p = malloc( sizeof *p + strlen( "hello" )); 
p->i = 1;
strcpy( p->c, "hello" );
```

So we allocate enough memory for the `struct` type (5 bytes) *plus* enough memory to store `"hello"`, which gives us (assuming little-endian)

```
   +---+ ----+
i: | 1 |     |
   +---+     |
   | 0 |     |
   +---+     |
   | 0 |     +---- size of struct foo
   +---+     |
   | 0 |     |
   +---+     |
c: |'h'|     |
   +---+ ----+
   |'e'|     |
   +---+     |
   |'l'|     |
   +---+     |
   |'l'|     +---- Extra memory for "hello"
   +---+     |
   |'o'|     |
   +---+     |
   | 0 |     |
   +---+ ----+
```

Why do we make `c` an array of size 1 instead of a pointer?  If we made `c` a pointer, like

```
struct foo { int i; char *c };
```

then this trick doesn't work, because all `c` can store is an *address*, not data.

C allows "flexible array members", where a size isn't needed in the declaration:

```
struct foo { int i; char c[] };
```

However, C++ does not (yet) support this, so you have to specify a non-zero size.

Comment: The explanation why the trick doesn’t work with a pointer is not really correct: a `char[1]` can *also* not store a string (in fact, this is simply UB in C++, although I omitted mentioning this in my answer). The reason this works isn’t that `char[1]` can store more data than a pointer, but rather that if we used a pointer then C++ would interpret the bytes at `offsetof(foo, c)` as a pointer to some *other* memory location, not as the start of a string. Because it’s declared as `char[1]`, C++ performs array-to-pointer decay upon usage of `c`, and we end up with a pointer *to* `c[0]`.

Answer (score 2):

it is a very old trick.

```
typedef struct 
{
    size_t size;
    char str[1];
} mystring_t;

mystring_t *allocate(size_t size)
{
    return malloc(sizeof(mystring_t) + size -1);
}
```

Then you can easily reallocate it as the flexible part is always at the end of the struct.

In newer C versions

```
typedef struct 
{
    size_t size;
    char str[];
} mystring_t;
```

or using gcc

```
typedef struct 
{
    size_t size;
    char str[0];
} mystring_t;
```